# parent directory of file not writable

Tags: android

I am getting error like this "

> error:parent Directory of a file not
>   writable"

in android.

I've included `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, but it's not working.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to write to (absolute path) ?

Answer (score 3):

Having that permission doesn't allow you to write anywhere.

You should get the writable path using: [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from having correct permissions and a writeable path, as was already mentioned by Macarse, you might also want to check if the SDcard mounted is writable (check the **Permissions** tab in the **FileExplorer** view it should be something like **d---rwxr-x**).

If not then remount the SDcard(there are adb commands to do this but are risky, I think). 
My usual course of action is switching off the phone and removing and then reinserting the SDcard. Sometimes just switching off the phone helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error too, only I'm trying to write to internal storage. Any ideas on how to fix the error?

Never mind. I figured it out. Data has to be written to the file streams as bytes if saving to internal storage.